# File migration from File server to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core

Currently we are storing application documents to our own file share. We send these documents to interface partner application as well (share file path) and they read the file content in their application using stand I/O operation. We have decided to to move files from own file share to AWS S3. We have decided to use AWS Lambda service to read and write the document to AWS S3.

Problem statement. 
We need two type of access, one has full read/write access and other has only read only access. We want to expose single WEB API URL with two methods Get and Post. How can we implement authentication and authorization in this architecture.

We don't want to give full access to interface partner because it because security risk and they are not authorize to get full access on our application bucket.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an IAM user with the role and restrict them as per your requirement.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-restrict-amazon-s3-bucket-access-to-a-specific-iam-role/
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/walkthrough1.html

```
{
        "Id": "bucketPolicy",
        "Statement": [
                {
                        "Action": "s3:*",
                        "Effect": "Deny",
                        "NotPrincipal": {
                                "AWS": [
                                        "arn:aws:iam::78343:user/alloweduser"
                                ]
                        },
                        "Resource": [
                                "arn:aws:s3:::test",
                                "arn:aws:s3:::test/*"
                        ]
                }
        ],
        "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. How to add two IAM user to the webAPI? I have single endpoint and two method.